# Using a "non resource" object with a tastypie api

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a tastypie based api, and I would like to use some api endpooint which do not match a resource like behaviour

eg. forgot password

I would still like it to be within the tastypie universe so I could use the Authorization/Throttling logic I have.

I would like to avoid using a `Resource` or a `ModelResource` because the only http verb I care is doing a post to this url, which will send a mail.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple django view instead of using the tastypie api? (using @require_POST)

Comment: So I could use the Authorization/Throttling logic I have already written for tastypie.

Comment: Can you just set appropriate `*_allowed_methods = ['POST']` attributes for `Resource` class?